# How to hinder PHP files to Global Access

Tags: php

I have some includes files and I don't want to expose them via HTTP. They are only used for being included into other PHP files.

Should I configure `.htaccess` file and add some lines to specify that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use .htaccess rules or put them outside of your web directory!

Try this:

```
<Files filename.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: What else can I do? I am working on local Apache server and I don't have such directory also I want to discover other ways as well.

Comment: You could use mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to a Front Controller and decide what to serve. So the requests don't match the directory structure anymore.

Comment: You probably have a directory like htdocs. If you put your files _outside_ this folder, they won't be accessible via HTTP and you can still include them as you would normally do.

Comment: Isn't just there a config line such as `block_global_access init.php`?

Comment: Please study the suggestions given. Your _block_global_access_ thinking can be achieved by .htaccess rules.

Comment: So can give me that rule then?

Comment: @fromvega let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1685/discussion-between-braveyard-and-fromvega)

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* put files, that you don't want to get accessed from outside, into a directory, that is accessible from outside, or in short: Move the files outside the document root.

Lets say

```
/path/to/htdocs/index.php
/path/to/privateFiles/include.php
```

In `index.php` you can use

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../privateFiles/include.php';
```

When you want to make it a little bit more portable, you can separate both directories from each other. Usually files from `privateFiles/` don't need to know about the files in `htdocs`. In `index.php` you can do something like

```
define('INCLUDES_PATH', '/path/to/privateFiles');
```

and then anywhere within your application

```
require INCLUDES_PATH . '/include.php';
```

When you want to move the private files around, you just need to change the constant in `index.php`.

Comment: I really like this answer. So much informative and elaborate. Thanks... +1

Answer (score 1):

If your included file is PHP, define a constant in your index/main code, check it in the include files

Index.php

```
<?php
define('INDEX_LOADED',TRUE);
include('include.php');
?>
```

Include.php

```
<?php
if(!defined('INDEX_LOADED'))
  die('not to be accessed directly');
// rest of code here
?>
```