# Execute a script, but not let users access it

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hinder PHP files to Global Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772011/how-to-hinder-php-files-to-global-access)

For a project I'm working on, I require("xxxx.php"); to include certain parts of my website into my site.

For example, I have header.php and my site just uses a simple require("header.php") to display to the world.

Now, how do I make it so the page include header.php's content, but make it so the user can't access it via

http://mywebsite.com/header.php

Comment: I prefer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6796718/451969) to that duplicate question. Move the files off the web accessible path, or make the directory they're in require authentication.

Comment: You should specify which web server are you using. Majority assume Apache, but that may not be the case.

Comment: I'm currently working on a localhost server (XAMPP) so I am in fact using Apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the file somewhere outside the DocumentRoot of the webserver.

Comment: Sometimes, when using shared hosting, your hoster won't give you a directory outside DocumentRoot, though. If this is the case, you can use `.htaccess` -- I have put an example in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Setup the webserver so that:

1. You have a public directory, where your accessible files reside, say static media + index.php and so on
2. Have a resources directory, that is outside your public folder.
3. Setup the webserver to serve from the public directory
4. Include like this:

   require("../private/header.php");

Answer (score 3):

You could define a constant in your index file and then in your `header.php` you would check so this constant exists.

```
// check if the header.php file is accessed directly
if (!define('MY_SECRET_CONSTANT')) {
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the answers: there's a gazillion ways to do this, here's two pretty simple ones that do not require you to change your directory structure:

In `index.php` and other files that include `header.php`:

```
define('INCLUDED', true);
require 'header.php';
```

In `header.php`:

```
if(!defined('INCLUDED')){
  die('Forbidden'); // or you could redirect to home ... whatever you want :)
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can forbid access via `.htaccess`. Thus, you don't even have to touch your code:

```
<Files header.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

If your includes are all in one directory, you can simply deny access to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can either work with htaccess to ensure that special files are not viewed. The same can be achieved through a virtualhost entry.

A best pratice is to create a /web folder which is "the root" for your application and store everything which should be accessable. Other folders go anywhere else and are included into scripts which are desgined to get accessed by the user.

Your structure could look like this:

```
/var/www/mySite/inc/header.php
/var/www/mySite/web/index.php (including ../inc/header.php)
/var/www/mySite/web/css/style.css
```

Your apache virtual host would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com

    # Basic stuff
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/mySite/web"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/mySite/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the inc folder cannot be accessed through your domain as your web folder is the root for everyone comming from the url. Your scripts on the other hand can of course navigate lower than that and including scripts from anywhere.